# C++ template argument deduction is failing with error "candidate template ignored" when arguments include std::function... why?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have the following functions:

```
template <class InType, class OutType>
OutType foo(const InType &a, std::function<OutType (const InType &)> func)
{
    return func(a);
}

template <class T>
T bar(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I can call them like so:

```
double x = foo<int, double>(1, [] (const int &v) { return float(v) * 1.5f; });
double y = bar<int>(1.0, 2.0);
```

...and use template argument deduction with bar

```
double z = bar(1.0, 2.0);
```

...but if I try to use template argument deduction with foo:

```
double w = foo(1, [] (const int &v) { return float(v) * 1.5f; });
```

It fails with this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'foo'
    double w = foo(1, [] (const int &v) { return float(v) * 1.5f; });
               ^~~
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-1 (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against '(lambda at ../path/to/file.cpp:x:y)'
OutType foo(const InType &a, std::function<OutType (const InType &)> func)
        ^
```

Why is that? From my vantage point it's obvious what the argument types should be deduced as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions, that happens later during overload resolution. If you were to pass a std::function directly, it would deduce properly. It can't implicitly construct a `std::function` from your lambda without the type of the `std::function` to know whether it's possible. I know to us it looks like there is enough information for the compiler to properly deduce the types involved, but this is a constraint.

Comment: Type deduction only considers *some* implicit conversions. Not ones that involve converting constructors.

Comment: It's too bad this is the case. Otherwise it'd be possible to express some power logic without C++'s typical verbosity and template shenanigans.